# Use postfix and spamassassin packages on CentOS 6 to reject SPAM - without custom users and scripts

Tags: centos, postfix, centos6, spam, spamassassin

Here is what I'm trying at my CentOS 6.5 Linux server:

1. Installed postfix and spamassassin packages
2. Configured Postfix - it works well (I omit details here)
3. Added `-x` to the SPAMDOPTIONS in **/etc/sysconfig/spamassassin**
4. Added the following 2 lines to the **/etc/postfix/master.cf**

Here:

```
smtp         inet n - n - - smtpd -o content_filter=spamassassin
spamassassin unix - n n - - pipe user=nobody argv=/usr/bin/spamc -f -e /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -f ${sender} ${recipient}
```

Unfortunately, when I send the test SPAM mail with the subject

```
XJS*C4JDBQADN1.NSBN3*2IDNEN*GTUBE-STANDARD-ANTI-UBE-TEST-EMAIL*C.34X
```

it still comes through! (And the subject isn't rewritten - despite `rewrite_header Subject [SPAM]` in the unmodified **/etc/mail/spamassassin/local.cf** file).

I wonder, what have I missed? My **/var/log/maillog** is below:

```
postfix/postfix-script[2546]: starting the Postfix mail system
postfix/master[2547]: daemon started -- version 2.6.6, configuration /etc/postfix
postfix/qmgr[2550]: D5B19807033: from=<bsdglVlCWcQAM@yandex.ru>, size=1843, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
postfix/qmgr[2550]: 831CA809733: from=<equipmentsup@saic.com>, size=41369, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
postfix/qmgr[2550]: 42B7A80A312: from=<minzhigroup55@minzhigroup.vicp.cc>, size=4399, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
postfix/qmgr[2550]: AED94809D29: from=<marketing@groupmenumagazine.co.uk>, size=28035, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
postfix/qmgr[2550]: E69AA809D3C: from=<>, size=3487, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
postfix/qmgr[2550]: 2BDE980A61B: from=<haky151@yahoo.co.jp>, size=4073, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
postfix/qmgr[2550]: 0D37280A51F: from=<info@c21.com>, size=7888, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
postfix/smtp[2552]: D5B19807033: host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.136.27] said: 421-4.7.0 [144.76.184.154      15] Our system has detected an unusual rate of 421-4.7.0 unsolicited mail originating from your IP address. To protect our 421-4.7.0 users from spam, mail sent from your IP address has been temporarily 421-4.7.0 rate limited. Please visit 421-4.7.0 http://www.google.com/mail/help/bulk_mail.html to review our Bulk 421 4.7.0 Email Senders Guidelines. l16si23407549wjr.0 - gsmtp (in reply to end of DATA command)
postfix/smtp[2552]: D5B19807033: to=<Abram.XXX@gmail.com>, orig_to=<XXX@simplex.ru>, relay=alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.25.27]:25, delay=6325, delays=6323/0/1.2/0.61, dsn=4.7.0, status=deferred (host alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.25.27] said: 421-4.7.0 [144.76.184.154      15] Our system has detected an unusual rate of 421-4.7.0 unsolicited mail originating from your IP address. To protect our 421-4.7.0 users from spam, mail sent from your IP address has been temporarily 421-4.7.0 rate limited. Please visit 421-4.7.0 http://www.google.com/mail/help/bulk_mail.html to review our Bulk 421 4.7.0 Email Senders Guidelines. f7si4794087pdm.22 - gsmtp (in reply to end of DATA command))
postfix/smtpd[2557]: connect from mail-ie0-f180.google.com[209.85.223.180]
postfix/smtpd[2557]: B3FFF809367: client=mail-ie0-f180.google.com[209.85.223.180]
postfix/cleanup[2561]: B3FFF809367: message-id=<CAADeyWgi9VjXoXoUXtTf0n4jp_WJzMd2q7C7zqkRpK7=eKhNGQ@mail.gmail.com>
postfix/qmgr[2550]: B3FFF809367: from=<alexander.XXX@gmail.com>, size=1767, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
spamd[2034]: spamd: connection from localhost [127.0.0.1] at port 42928
spamd[2034]: spamd: setuid to nobody succeeded
spamd[2034]: spamd: processing message <CAADeyWgi9VjXoXoUXtTf0n4jp_WJzMd2q7C7zqkRpK7=eKhNGQ@mail.gmail.com> for nobody:99
postfix/smtpd[2557]: disconnect from mail-ie0-f180.google.com[209.85.223.180]
spamd[2034]: spamd: identified spam (999.9/5.0) for nobody:99 in 0.2 seconds, 1730 bytes.
spamd[2034]: spamd: result: Y 999 - DKIM_SIGNED,DKIM_VALID,DKIM_VALID_AU,FREEMAIL_FROM,GTUBE,HTML_MESSAGE,T_TO_NO_BRKTS_FREEMAIL scantime=0.2,size=1730,user=nobody,uid=99,required_score=5.0,rhost=localhost,raddr=127.0.0.1,rport=42928,mid=<CAADeyWgi9VjXoXoUXtTf0n4jp_WJzMd2q7C7zqkRpK7=eKhNGQ@mail.gmail.com>,autolearn=no
postfix/pickup[2549]: 3124F80A3DA: uid=99 from=<alexander.XXX@gmail.com>
postfix/cleanup[2561]: 3124F80A3DA: message-id=<CAADeyWgi9VjXoXoUXtTf0n4jp_WJzMd2q7C7zqkRpK7=eKhNGQ@mail.gmail.com>
postfix/pipe[2562]: B3FFF809367: to=<Alexander.XXX@gmail.com>, orig_to=<webmaster@XXX.de>, relay=spamassassin, delay=0.59, delays=0.37/0.01/0/0.22, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via spamassassin service)
postfix/qmgr[2550]: B3FFF809367: removed
spamd[2032]: prefork: child states: II
postfix/qmgr[2550]: 3124F80A3DA: from=<alexander.XXX@gmail.com>, size=2843, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
```

Comment: you to edit your postfix mainf.cf

Comment: maybe you are missing the content_filter in /etc/postfix/main.cf, i used this how-to and i don't find any problem,http://andrewpuschak.com/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=centos_6_email_server

Comment: But I already have `smtpd -o content_filter=spamassassin` in the master.cf?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The point of my question (maybe I haven't stated it clearly enough) has been: how to combine Postfix and Spamassassin on CentOS **with minimal efforts**.

Here is my solution in only 5 steps:

1. `yum install spamassassin`
2. `chkconfig spamassassin on`
3. `useradd spam` (you can't omit this step!)
4. Add `/^Subject: \[SPAM\]/ DISCARD` to **/etc/postfix/header_checks** (consult **/etc/mail/spamassassin/local.cf** for the exact string to match)
5. Add the following 2 lines to **/etc/postfix/master.cf**:

(note the usage of the new `spam` user from the step 2):

```
smtp         inet n - n - - smtpd -o content_filter=spamassassin
spamassassin unix - n n - - pipe user=spam argv=/usr/bin/spamc -f -e /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -f ${sender} ${recipient}
```

Finally restart the **postfix** and **spamassassin** services.

Send a test SPAM mail to yourself using the GTUBE subject:

```
XJS*C4JDBQADN1.NSBN3*2IDNEN*GTUBE-STANDARD-ANTI-UBE-TEST-EMAIL*C.34X
```

See that mail being discarded in **/var/log/maillog**:

```
postfix/smtpd[2048]: connect from mail-ig0-f176.google.com[209.85.213.176]
postfix/smtpd[2048]: 333F28007C1: client=mail-ig0-f176.google.com[209.85.213.176]
postfix/cleanup[2052]: 333F28007C1: message-id=<CAADeyWiTN=Nfmd6Z6P92arctGjZcRgrRtgt3r9TAU+a-=8CGug@mail.gmail.com>
postfix/qmgr[2037]: 333F28007C1: from=<alexander.XXX@gmail.com>, size=1883, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
spamd[1643]: spamd: connection from localhost [127.0.0.1] at port 53400
spamd[1643]: spamd: setuid to spam succeeded
spamd[1643]: spamd: processing message <CAADeyWiTN=Nfmd6Z6P92arctGjZcRgrRtgt3r9TAU+a-=8CGug@mail.gmail.com> for spam:502
postfix/smtpd[2048]: disconnect from mail-ig0-f176.google.com[209.85.213.176]
spamd[1643]: spamd: identified spam (999.9/5.0) for spam:502 in 0.1 seconds, 1846 bytes.
spamd[1643]: spamd: result: Y 999 - DKIM_SIGNED,DKIM_VALID,DKIM_VALID_AU,FREEMAIL_FROM,GTUBE,HTML_MESSAGE scantime=0.1,size=1846,user=spam,uid=502,required_score=5.0,rhost=localhost,raddr=127.0.0.1,rport=53400,mid=<CAADeyWiTN=Nfmd6Z6P92arctGjZcRgrRtgt3r9TAU+a-=8CGug@mail.gmail.com>,autolearn=no
postfix/pickup[2036]: 92AE8809366: uid=502 from=<alexander.XXX@gmail.com>
postfix/cleanup[2052]: 92AE8809366: message-id=<CAADeyWiTN=Nfmd6Z6P92arctGjZcRgrRtgt3r9TAU+a-=8CGug@mail.gmail.com>
postfix/cleanup[2052]: 92AE8809366: discard: header Subject: [SPAM] XJS*C4JDBQADN1.NSBN3*2IDNEN*GTUBE-STANDARD-ANTI-UBE-TEST-EMAIL*C.34X from local; from=<alexander.XXX@gmail.com> to=<Alexander.XXX@gmail.com>
postfix/pipe[2053]: 333F28007C1: to=<Alexander.XXX@gmail.com>, orig_to=<webmaster@XXX.de>, relay=spamassassin, delay=0.51, delays=0.35/0.01/0/0.15, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via spamassassin service)
postfix/qmgr[2037]: 333F28007C1: removed
spamd[1642]: prefork: child states: II
```

Comment: You can also see it reinjected and sent back to the sender in that log....

Comment: Does this cause backscatter? If so why since step 4 looks like it discards spam?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so basically, you are piping the email into spamc, and then having spamc email the output to the recipient (well,actually remailing to the sender, but I think the intent was to remail to the recip)..

No offense, but that is nuts.

If you want mail to be rejected based on the SA score, you're going to need a milter or policy deamon to do that. Spamassassin doesn't reject mail, it only scores it.  Avamisd-new, or spamass-milter could work for you.

As to why spamassassin is not rewriting, it probably is, its just not sending the modified version of the email to where you are expecting it to.

the original QueueID is `3124F80A3DA`. Spamassassin is remailing it as QueueID `B3FFF809367` **back to the sender!**

Looking at the rest of your log dump, it appears you're doing that with all the incoming spam - and Gmail is even "deferring" your IP due to the volume of it.

Don't reinvent the wheel and accidentally get blacklisted in the process. You want to **reject** incoming spam based on SA score, use a milter or policy daemon.

Comment: I don't think it's nuts, because I'm trying to follow these 2 guides: http://www.debuntu.org/postfix-and-spamassassin-how-to-filter-spam-page-2/ and http://howto.gumph.org/content/run-spamassassin-with-postfix/ And yes, I'd like to resubmit the mail (but with the rewritten subject - which doesn't work for some reason) - so that I can reject the mail with header_checks (later, don't have it in my config files right now). As for Gmail deferring - of course - that is why I am trying to add Spamassassin in the 1st place. Here is the picture: http://www.akadia.com/services/postfix_spamassassin.html

Comment: Your setup is resubmitting the mail alright - but not the way you want it to. Do you see in the log where the sender and recip are getting reversed?

Comment: If you absolutely must use a post-queue content filter, at least do it the way http://www.postfix.org/FILTER_README.html suggests. Those two tutorials you referenced are dangerously wrong.  For starters, you need whatever you pipe the mail into to return an appropriate status back to postfix to let postfix know what to do with the message (not something spamc is going to do).